# angular ui-grid api not available not bounding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

```
vm.gridOptions = {
        enableSorting: true,
        columnDefs: [
            {field: 'deviceName'},
            {field: 'ip'},
            {
                field: 'Action', enableSorting: false,
                cellTemplate: '/monitoring_page/modals/buttonTemplate.html'
            }
        ],
        data: vm.dataStack,
        onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
            vm.gridApiSource = gridApi;
        }
    };
```

This is my ui-grid grid option.

in which I am declaring vm.gridApiSource but it not bounding to vm.

I am assigning var vm = this;

Please give hint why gridApiSource not bounding to this;

my plunker link
http://plnkr.co/edit/Oxo8XdQCysOUvfvhD82z?p=preview

When I press delete icon and delete option on the modal. It will throw error gridApiSource is undefined.

Comment: it will happen only when `onRegisterApi` is called, where is the call for that function??

Comment: Does it call when ui-grid="gridOptions" assigning to div in HTML?
because  I am getting value for vm.gridApiSource in controller loading inside at onRegisterApi function.

Comment: Yes and I make a mistake.  When I back from controller my controller reloading so it is undefined.  So i made a service for it.